# Inner join on delete statement with apache derby

Tags: sql, derby

I have used the following syntax to select the needed row's:

```
select * from Customer_Coupon inner join Company_Coupon on
Customer_Coupon.COUPON_Id =Company_Coupon.COUPON_Id where COMP_Id = 123;
```

What syntax should I use to delete the same row's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [DELETE statment](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.14/ref/rrefsqlj35981.html) with an IN operator:

```
DELETE FROM Customer_Coupon WHERE COUPON_ID IN (
   SELECT COUPON_ID FROM Customer_Coupon INNER JOIN Company_Coupon ON
   Customer_Coupon.COUPON_Id =Company_Coupon.COUPON_Id WHERE COMP_Id = 123
);
```

This will delete all rows in the Customer_Coupon table where the `COUPON_ID` is returned by the inner SELECT.

Comment: Thanks! That helps a lot!